# How to display list of items in order without shifting data using angular

Tags: angular, typescript

**Scenarios:** As per client requirement we need to display list of orders in two rows.
To display list of orders in two columns we used `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. We designed the element as follows.

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="order-list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="order-wrap">
        <span>25-02-2019</span>
        <div class="order-container">
          <span>Order ID : 1   </span>
          <a href="#">Download PDF</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="order-wrap">
        <span>25-02-2019</span>
        <div class="order-container">
          <span>Order ID : 2   </span>
          <a href="#">Download PDF</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="order-wrap">
        <span>25-02-2019</span>
        <div class="order-container">
          <span>Order ID : 3   </span>
          <a href="#">Download PDF</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="order-wrap">
        <span>25-02-2019</span>
        <div class="order-container">
          <span>Order ID : 4    </span>
          <a href="#">Download PDF</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**app.component.scss**

```
.order-list {
  width: 600px;
  .order-wrap {
    width: 250px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    margin: 2px;
    .order-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
  }
}
```

**OutPut:**

[image]

**Problem:** We are facing issues while displaying single item display. Our order contains following fields.**“Order Date”** after that **“Order Id”** and **“Order Download link”**. If we have more than one order or “even number “of items, they are displaying as expected.

But if we have “odd” number of items then UI got disturbed.Means the “order id and Download” link are shifted to another row as below.

If we have odd number items like 1,3,5 7,..etc

[image]

If we have single record

[image]

In above screen if you observe the orderid and downlod options got shifted.

But client expecting all are in same div or same order.

[image]

Also if we have more items we need to enable vertical scroll bar.

Request you to please suggest changes in my code.

I created a StackBlitz demo link also. Please check

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8njlux?file=src%2Forderlist%2Forderlist.component.html

Comment: Make a stackblitz demo.

Comment: @StefaniToto Hi please find the stackblitz demo link.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8njlux?file=src%2Forderlist%2Forderlist.component.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-txijnq?file=src%2Forderlist%2Forderlist.component.html

Comment: Regarding virtual scrolliing you can use from cdk. https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

Comment: @StefaniToto thanks for your suggestion. But it won't work for me. I need to display list of data and display them in 2 column rows. My problem is different. i have issue with odd number columns.

Comment: You had issue bcz of styling. I modified your code into 2 columns and if you comment one of data there will be no issue